FCM erro : Permission denied: Consumer 'projects/undefined' has been suspended
Sending FCM notification for android using nodejs backend, everything is correct as per example.
Below are the FCM options:
    this.fcmOptions = {
        host: 'fcm.googleapis.com',
        path: `/v1/projects/${project_id}/messages:send`,
        method: 'POST'
    };

node Code worked for me once but now it started giving error.
Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied: Consumer 'projects/undefined' has been suspended.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CONSUMER_SUSPENDED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "fcm.googleapis.com",
          "consumer": "projects/undefined"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Anyone please help to solve above error!

When you're debugging this, what is the string value of project_id?  The error message is suggesting that it might not be what you expect.

Well seems your project_id does not have a value  thus your path is wrong...

Ah!  my bad  i used class in node js and was accessing variable without this :(
@derpirscher Thanks
